# Тип поля для time() в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, время, timestamp

Какой тип поля в MySQL правильно использовать для хранения Unix timestamp ( time() PHP)?

Answer (score 1):

Это `TIMESTAMP`.

[тут немного разъясняют](https://habrahabr.ru/post/61391/)